# Typographic tweaks for IE using conditional CSS... or something else?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, conditional-comments

I'm trying to create a design blog and gallery for myself and that's why I'm being a bit experimental with CSS3. I achieved the result I wanted for other browsers and now IE is giving me a headache.

I created rotated date markers for my blog posts with CSS like this:

```
.metadata {
margin-left: -108px;
margin-top: 140px;
width: 140px;
position: absolute;
text-align: right;
} 

.postdate {
display: block;
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
font-size: 70px;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Okay, how I did it is probably not so important. Anyway: I tried rotating the text in IE as well, and I managed to do it with the IE-specific code, but the rendered result was simply so awful that I didn't want to use it. And now, without the rotate code and such, the date markers are naturally nowhere near where they should be in IE.

I wished to create a completely different look for the date markers in IE using conditional CSS, but I'm not sure how, my first time trying anything like that.

```
<!--[if IE ]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="iecss.css"  type="text/css" media="screen">
<![endif]-->
```

In that iecss-file I included the same CSS classes with slightly different rules: at first I only tried to drop the font size by 50 pixels. I only have IE 8 on my computer, and it had absolutely no effect there. I previewed my website with IE NetRenderer which implied the text size change *did work* in IE 7 (well, actually in IE 6 too, but I'm reluctant to talk about the other things that happened to the design).

So why didn't it do anything in IE 8 and (according to the NetRenderer) IE 9? I also tried using [if gte IE 8] but it didn't do anything either.

Is the problem that when IE understands the rules in the main CSS file and has no trouble displaying the result like it should be, it cannot override the effect with new CSS rules for the same classes?

Is there a way to make all versions of IE completely ignore those CSS rules and follow others (which would make the date marker look completely different in IE)? Or, is there a way to tell IE not to show the date marker at all? Since my site is just quite experimental to begin with, it would be no big deal not to show post dates in IE. Can PHP do the latter for me?

Comment: What doctype is specified in your html?

Comment: You can try Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/) for feature detection, which allows you to use CSS classes to determine whether a certain feature (e.g., 2D transforms) are supported.  This is typically better than browser detection.  And be sure to include the non-prefixed CSS as well!

Comment: @raina77ow I started modifying an existing Wordpress layout (I guess it was the default one)
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: @TomPietrosanti That sounded good and I tried it, but I cannot seem to get it work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but all of my test browsers display the non-prefixed CSS... Dunno if I'm using a wrong prefix or if the js-file isn't even recognized to begin with.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give you some more in-depth help at the moment - I'm crunched for time - but I wanted to share the suggestion at least.  If I get some time, I'll see if I can help some more!  Best of luck in the meantime!

Answer (score 0):

For IE 9 support add:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

For IE 8 and lower add:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

Number 3 is for -90 (270) degrees, 0 is for 0 degrees, 1 is 90 degrees and 2 is 180 degrees.

Links: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Eqkjh/2/ 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for a solution how to rotate text for IE as I tried just those codes, successfully rotated it, but thought IE renders the result looking so ugly that I don't want to use it there. It seems to lack anti-aliasing and be placed in a different position from other browsers.